# RSACryptoServiceProvider .NET License

Tags: .net

I am using an the RSACryptoServiceProvider class in my application. To use the RSA encryption public key and private. This component is inside the Microsoft Library `System.Security.Cryptography`. However, I have a doubt. I will sell this product, so will I need any license from RSA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any license because System.Security.Cryptography is distributed with .NET Framework.

Comment: Yes, I thought. Just wanted to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: The company I am working for have developed several software solutions (ERP) that used RSA encryption. No license was needed and that is a sure thing because the client was a state institution and they had done a full audit of the components regarding licenses and copyrights.

Comment: rfect. now I can use without fear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I checked, [RSA was a cryptographical algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA). So no, you don't need a license.